# How to choose multiple lines from one input and save them to different files at once?

Tags: bash, text-processing

I need to process large amount of data from stdout, but I need only several lines from them.

Let's say I want to append some data from line beginning with `Label 3` to the file `F3.csv`, and some data from line beginning with `Label 5` to the file `F5.csv`.

#### Example input - from STDOUT

```
Label 1 25
Label 2 60
Label 3 70
Label 4 95
Label 5 100
```

#### Output

Append `70` to `F3.csv` and `100` to `F5.csv`.

I'd like to know if it's possible to do this and if it is, then how.

Do you know any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is pretty easy to do with Awk:

```
awk '/Label 3/ { print $3 >>"F3.csv" } /Label 5/ { print $3>>"F5.csv" }'
```

This will *append* the value for lines starting with *Label 3* and *Label 5* to the file *F3.csv* and *F5.csv* correspondingly.

This can also be written a bit more compactly:

```
awk '/Label 3|Label 5/ { print $3 >> "F"$2".csv"}'
```

using a fact that target filename can be deduced from the label suffix

(Thanks @don_crissti !)

Answer (score 2):

try this -

```
#sed -e '/Label\ 3/w F3.csv' -e '/Label\ 5/w F5.csv' sed.txt
Label 1 25
Label 2 60
Label 3 70
Label 4 95
Label 5 100
#head F?.csv
==> F3.csv <==
Label 3 70

==> F5.csv <==
Label 5 100
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd just like to add, that I need to append only values, not the original label.